# A villager asked me to take a picture and send it to them. How do I do that?

Tags: animal-crossing-city-folk

A villager walked up to me and asked me to take a picture of them, so I did. Then they asked me to send it to them. I assume that means attaching it to a letter. However, I can't figure out how to do that, since I can't drag it like other items. How do I go about sending that picture?

Answer (score -3):

When you have a G-Mail,and the villager too,you can attach a file on it,when you're writing an E-Mail to him,somewhere.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming Stack Exchange, a.k.a. Arqade! E-mail (G-Mail or otherwise) doesn't exist inside Animal Crossing, so I'm guessing this was a joke. But since it doesn't actually answer the question, your answer was downvoted. This site works a little differently than forums: you can check out [our tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about how.